# Code in Python 3.6 gives ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code and I'm getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.constant'. How can I fix the error?

```
import scipy.integrate as sci
import scipy.constant as scc
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython import get_ipython
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

def f(T):
    n=6.022*(10**28)
    Od=429
    V=10**(-3)
    ft=lambda x: ((x**4)*math.exp(x)/(((math.exp(x))-1**2))

    b = Od/T
    a=0

    C=9*V*n((T/Od)**3)*scc.k*(sci.quad(ft,a, b.any(),limit=10))[0]
    return C

T1=np.arange(5,500,1)

plt.plot(T1,f(T1),'r-')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By correcting the misspelled scipy.constant into [scipy.constants](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/constants.html).